# Diablo 3: Reaper of souls. Problem with save data

Tags: ps4, diablo-iii-console

I'm aware that the whole game size is almost 32 gb with the Reaper of souls. I deleted the game and install it again, and now it just install 18gb. When I try to go into the menu it says "Your save data is from a previous version of Diablo III. If you continue, it will no longer work if the update is removed" I don't want to loss my data. So, do you guys know anything?

Comment: I don't believe your data will be lost. I recommend checking for updates to the Application. This can be done from the main PS4 screen. Highlight the game, and press the options button. There should be a check for updates section there, though I'm at work now and can't verify the exact process.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yep, I did that. The game says is the last update. So, i'm not very sure what to do.

Comment: the change in game size is probably because Blizz refactors their games from time to time to reduce redundant and useless code especially after updates and patches that change tons of things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls for PS4 has a unique way of warning the player about game updates. However, this is not a warning that your save data is gone; rather, it is warning you about reverting updates. In the event that you play the game in a non-updated state, your save games will not work.

Your current saves will be converted to the newest update, but if you roll back, those saves will exist, but cannot be loaded. The simple answer is; don't roll back your updates!

Comment: Just FTR, XB1 version of D3:ROS gets this same message on game load, after every update.